# Least privilege required for export documents from GCP Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a service to export documents from our Firestore database on a regular cadence for backup. The sdk call used to do this can be found [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/v1.FirestoreAdminClient.html#exportDocuments).

What I am trying to determine is what are the **least privileges required** on the Firebase store to allow this (exportDocuments) action. From what it appears Admin is required. Though hoping there may be something more restrictive which can be used.

Comment: From the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#before_you_begin), it looks like the role *Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin* (`roles/datastore.importExportAdmin`) is required. However, looking at the permissions associated with this role (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam#iam_roles), I think that you only require `datastore.databases.export` permission (*Export entities from a database*). Unfortunately, the most restrictive predefined role with this permission is `roles/datastore.importExportAdmin`. You may have to create a custom role.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the comment [@norbjd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7804058/norbjd)!

There is a role, `roles/datastore.importExportAdmin`, "Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin" which provides the permissions required to export documents from datastore. Though it also includes `datastore.databases.import` which is an extra, unneeded permission.

```
appengine.applications.get
datastore.databases.export
datastore.databases.import
datastore.operations.cancel
datastore.operations.get
datastore.operations.list
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
```

The thought is to setup a new role only including `datastore.databases.export` permission. It seems this is not possible in Google Cloud to add `datastore.databases.export` to a custom role

> Not supported in custom roles
>   These permissions cannot be added to custom roles. Instead, you can grant predefined roles that contain the permissions you need.

Adding the pre-defined role is not helpful as that is what we are trying to break up.

Solution: Provide the service account with the role: **Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin** (`roles/datastore.importExportAdmin`) and explicit write permisison to the bucket that the documents are being exported into.